# EstimatedProcess estimate biased?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting, random, time-series

I'm estimating the ARProcess parameters of a set of 1000 time series generated with an `ARProcess` and  `RandomFunction`. Each time series is short (34 points), so I expect quite some noise, but on average I expect to see my input parameter (0.48) back. However, it looks like `EstimatedProcess` systematically underestimates this parameter. Is this an error or is this expected and explainable? A colleague of mine claims that Matlab doesn't have this issue.

```
Through[{Mean, StandardDeviation}[
    (EstimatedProcess[#, ARProcess[{a}, v]] & /@ 
     RandomFunction[ARProcess[{.48}, 1], {1, 34}, 1000]["Paths"]
    )[[All, 1, 1]]]
]
```

> {0.388234, 0.156857}

Fixing the variance term v on 1 in the `EstimatedProcess` does not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe `Matlab` has the bias.  First, one would need to check on if the estimates are the same in *Mathematica* and *Matlab* (when given the same options).  (I don't have a copy of *Matlab* so I'll compare using *R*.)  If those estimates are the same, then checking on the data creation process would need to be examined.

Given the following 34 data points:

```
x = {0.762581453, 1.432767666, 1.729161761, 1.487405427, 1.795480445, 
     1.029690811, 0.569472382, -0.023059941, -0.156831325, 0.429908074,
    -0.632142053, -0.262679203, 0.701932332, 1.051120549, 0.11186958,
    -0.319916758, -1.550805411, -0.106264866, -0.285184731, -0.847601482,
    -2.4669689, -2.528088859, 0.048553687, 1.714408932, 2.314229506,
    -0.459274584, -1.224375149, -1.132357697, -1.307473818, -0.729989006,
     0.814224672, 0.798828446, -0.587769684, 1.204700686};
```

Estimation in *Mathematica*:

```
EstimatedProcess[x, ARProcess[{r}, v], ProcessEstimator -> "MaximumLikelihood"]
(* ARProcess[{0.579037}, 0.904965] *)
```

Estimation in *R*:

```
x = c(0.762581453,1.432767666,1.729161761,1.487405427,1.795480445,1.029690811,     
0.569472382,-0.023059941,-0.156831325,0.429908074,-0.632142053,-0.262679203,
0.701932332,1.051120549,0.11186958,-0.319916758,-1.550805411,-0.106264866,
-0.285184731,-0.847601482,-2.4669689,-2.528088859,0.048553687,1.714408932,
2.314229506,-0.459274584,-1.224375149,-1.132357697,-1.307473818,-0.729989006,
0.814224672,0.798828446,-0.587769684,1.204700686)

estimate = ar(x, method="mle", order.max=1)
c(estimate$ar,estimate$var.pred)
# [1] 0.5799839 0.9040807
```

Those two sets of estimates are close enough such that any bias that might be due to differences in estimation are ruled out.  That leaves 2 other possibilities:  (1) Bias in the data creation process and (2) bias associated with the maximum likelihood estimator.

I don't have time to check out (1) but if one raises the sample length from 34 to 1,000, the bias seems to go away.  That suggests that it's likely the usual sample size bias that maximum likelihood estimators can have.

```
Through[{Mean, 
   StandardDeviation}[(EstimatedProcess[#, ARProcess[{a}, v]] & /@ 
     RandomFunction[ARProcess[{.48}, 1], {1, 1000}, 1000]["Paths"])[[All, 1, 1]]]]

(* {0.476582, 0.0267468} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was aware that with increasing sample size the bias seems to appear. So, I'm particularly interested in the short sample bias. I have the feeling that this is not just a MLE issue as you hypothesize, as other available methods like MethodOfMoments and SpectralEstimator show a similar bias. I'm currently running the Matlab equivalent for 100,000 paths (will take the whole night as it is pretty slow), but my initial impression is that it has a bias as well, but a smaller one (looks like it typically answers around 0.43 instead of Mathematica's 0.4).

Comment: The Matlab calculation returned 0.42, so it is biased as well (though perhaps less than Mathematica).

Comment: Bias is associated with a statistical estimation method (maximum likelihood, least-squares, Yule-Walker, etc.) and not with an implementation in *R*, *Mathematica*, or *MATLAB*.  There is a specific bias with the maximum likelihood estimation process.  That simulations with *MATLAB* are closer than with *Mathematica" to the "parent parameter" of the data generation process does not make *MATLAB* less biased.  It is how close to the "true" bias that counts.

Comment: The following articles should be helpful:  "The Bias of Autoregressive Coefficient Estimators"(http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1988.10478672), 
"A program to calculate the empirical bias in autocorrelation estimators"
(http://www.psicothema.com/pdf/781.pdf (includes MATLAB code)), and 
"On the bias of the least squares estimator for the first order autoregressive process" 
(https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00050668).

Comment: Thanks Jim, I'll look into them.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Mathematica appears to use the "MethodOfMoments" method to calculate ARProcess parameters. This is involves calculating the lagged auto-covariances of the input data. However, these are likely calculated by calling the Mathematica "CovarianceFunction" function. The definition given for the covariance calculation (under "Details" in the "CovarianceFunction" Reference) calculates the lagged moments, but uses 1/N to average the squared-deviations from the mean. This is often done, but is known to be a biased estimate. It's particularly noticeable for long lags and short data arrays. (It tends to disappear for long data sets.) In my opinion, they should have used 1/(N-h), where "h" is the lag, which is unbiased. You might try specifying a different method in ARProcess (such as "MaximumLikelihood"). The downside is that these alternative methods tend to be much slower, and probably unusable if your trying to calculate a vector ARProcess.